# Modal Swal está comprimindo/quebrando o fundo da página

Tags: modal, flask, background, sweetalert2

Tenho uma aplicação que estou fiz com FLASK, onde utilizei alguns recursos modais, sendo um deles o SweetAlert2.
Ao abrir o modal, o fundo da página é comprimido na parte superior. O CSS do body/html é o seguinte:

```
body,html{
height: 100% !important;
background: radial-gradient(#ffffff, #a8a8a8) !important;
backface-visibility: hidden;
/* background-size: cover; */
}
```

Estou afirmando que o fundo comprime na parte superior, pois ao dar zoom na imagem é possível verificar que o gradiente radial não foi cortado, ou seja, ele foi comprimido. Parece que o modal que é a causa disso, pois só acontece ao abrir o swal.

Outra situação que percebi foi: tentei mudar o fundo do Swal, tanto pelas funções de sua documentação, quanto alterando pelo css/classe (mesmo utilizando !important) e nada aconteceu.

[image: Background cortado, parte inferior aparece um "branco" e o fundo original fica na parte superior]

Comment: Não consigo reproduzir o erro do gradient. Para mudar o fundo do swal basta passar a opção 'background'.

Comment: @tomasantunes Peço perdão por não ter sido claro, vou colocar a resposta que encontrei abaixo.

Answer (score 0):

Fui procurando o problema pela devtools do Chromer e encontrei a classe do Swal que modificava o fundo, ela chama "swal2-hight-auto".

Procurei pela classe no google e encontrei uma discussão no github ([LINK](https://github.com/Basaingeal/Razor.SweetAlert2/issues/816)), onde um cara apenas obriga a classe a ocupar toda a tela.
Segue o código:

```
body.swal2-height-auto {
  height: 100% !important
}
```